# Scrolling Techniques for Material Design doesnt work

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make my app with the material design guides and I have a problem. I'm trying to use the scrolling techniques but doesn't work in cellphone. I looked in the internet but I can't notice my mistake. This is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.kriegerlab.recyclerview.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Any about where is the mistake? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok! I solved this with:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
```